# What's the consistency strength of intuitive partitioning and negation of Banach-Tarski paradox?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic, set-partition

Let $\forall X,P \ (P \text{ is a partition of X} \to |P| \leq |X|)$ be intuitive partitioning $``\sf IP"$.

In English it means that every set can only be partitioned into pieces the amount of which is less than or equal to the amount of elements in it.

> Question: What's the consistency strength of $$\sf ZF+IP+\neg BT$$, where BT is [Banach-Tarski](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox) paradox?

$\sf \neg BT$ is just a simple straightforward negation of Banach-Tarski paradox.

Comment: Can you elaborate on the precise meaning of your IP axiom?

Comment: And for that matter, the not BT axiom?

Comment: IP already has a name. It's called the Partition Principle (I have written about it extensively on this site and on MathOverflow). And we do not know that it is strictly weaker than AC. But we do know it implies there are non-measurable sets.

Comment: is it known if IP implies BT or not?

Comment: This might be a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2912186/is-there-a-way-to-prove-the-banach-tarski-theorem-from-just-the-partition-princi